# "2x" Button reduces clarity

Tags: ios

I have an iPhone app that looks good on retina iphones but when it's on an iPad and someone taps the "2x" button in the corner, the app is expanded and thus the quality is reduced.

What's the best way to handle this? Can I use higher quality images somehow?

Comment: ipad images should be of different(greater) dimensions than iphone images. Is this iphone only app running on ipad ?

Comment: Make a universal app with a real iPad UI?

Comment: The best way would be to actually implement an iPad version of the app, instead of letting the device scale up a version made for iPhones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create an app, there are two options, You create a separate interface for the iPad, or you don't.

If you create a separate interface, it will load up, and there will be no 2x option.

If your app does not have an iPad interface, the iPad will display the iPhone screen, and 2x will just stretch the pixels.

So if you want a clear iPad app, you will have to create a iPad interface -

Separate storyboard - If you have used storyboard.

Separate Xib - If you have used XIB

Different frames etc - If you have used code to create the UI.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is nothing you can do in this situation.  The 2x button takes the retina iPhone screen and simply scales it up.